# How to stretch the controls as per the page size in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a listview of width set to Auto. When I run the windows app, it opens in normal size(not maximized). But when I maximize the window, the listview's width will be same and the space to its right is empty.

normal size
|_________________________|
Maximized
|_________________________|...........

even though the window is now in full screen occupied.
Please guide me in workin on this.

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackPanel`, by design, does not care about visual space.  It aims to take up the smallest amount of space possible.  You can leave the innermost `StackPanel` that wraps the radio buttons in place, but your outer layout containers should be changed to `Grid` or, as in my example below, `DockPanel`:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="445" Width="515">

    <DockPanel Name="spDataFlow" Margin="0,45,0,0" >
        <DockPanel x:Name="stkPnlDataFlow" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Margin="20,15,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <RadioButton Name="rdbtnUploadData" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" Content="Upload Data" IsEnabled="True"  CommandParameter="UploadAll"/>
                <RadioButton Name="rdbtnDownloadData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" Content="Download Data" Margin="20,0" CommandParameter="DownloadAll"/>
                <RadioButton Name="rdbtnUploadSelected" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" Content="Update Data" Margin="10,0"  CommandParameter="UpdateSelected"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the help.. But somehow this couldnt work out.

I still have blank area on right of the screen

thanks
ramm

Comment: What do you want to occupy that space?  Do you want the radio buttons to be spread far apart?  If that's the case, you have to replace the inner-most StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that by default the ListView control automatically fills all available space so it is very strange that have such an issue. Could you paste your code?